# Конструкторы и закрытие VS с++

Tags: c++, конструктор

Начинаю изучение с++, при написании программы (задание ниже) после запуске отладки в VS2019 VS закрывается полностью возможно ли исправить?
И ещё по заданию:
Разработать класс для представления времени суток (с точностью до секунд). Класс должен
обеспечивать задание времени от 0 час 0 мин 0 сек до 23 час 59 мин 59 сек. Желательно, чтобы
совокупный размер полей, используемых для хранения времени, был как можно меньше. В main
должны быть продемонстрировано применение методов класса.
Класс должен содержать:
− конструктор времени по заданным количествам часов, минут, секунд; при задании неверного
времени должно генерироваться исключение;
возникает ошибка после запуска отладки "Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall time::time(void)" (??0time@@QAE@XZ) в функции _main  ConsoleApplication2 C:\Users\NARYAD\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.obj    1
" как исправить это (код ниже)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class time {
    int hour, minute, second;
public:
    time(int, int, int);
    time(char*);
    time();
    void settime1()
    {
        cout << "Введите час: ";
        cin >> hour;
        cout << "Введите минуты: ";
        cin >> minute;
        cout << "Введите секунды: ";
        cin >> second;
        try 
        {
            if (hour > 24)
            {
                throw 1;
            }
        }
        catch (int i)
        {
            cout << "Ошибка №" << i << " Неверный час!!!!" << endl;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    time t1;  
    t1.settime1();
    time t2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну а где у вас конструкторы вашего `time`?

Comment: Разобрался, только вот как только консоль открывается как я и говорил VS сразу само закрывается без ошибок